# pandas: expand strings in a column to substrings and add them to the rows

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe containing many cloumns with multiple strings in each cell, and I would like to take substrings of the strings and add append them as a new column in a new dataframe with an extra column that describes the first column like the example below. I know how to do it for one column from the original dataframe, but I would like to do it for all the columns at once.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'First':  ['First string, second string, third string,...', 'NaN','First string, second string, third string,...'],
    'Second': ['NaN', 'First string, second string, third string,...','First string, second string, third string,...'],
    'third': ['First string, second string, third string,...', 'First string, second string, third string,...','NaN'],
    'forth': ['First string, second string, third string,...', 'NaN','First string, second string, third string,...'],
     ....
    }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['First','Second',...])
```

for one column:

```
  lst= df['first'].dropna().tolist()

  my_list= [x for xs in lst for x in xs.split(',')]

  df_new = pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns =['text'])
```

although I am not sure how I can add a second column about the same size as 'my_list' bearing the name of the previous column, so in this case 'first'.

desired output for one column:

```
 df_new:
    text             name
 0  First string     first
 1  second string    first
 2  third  string    first
    ...              ...
```

what I would like to happen is that all the column from df are added as rows to df_new while the column 'name' has cells with the name of the previous columns corresponding to the first column strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps!

```
#create the columns as rows 
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'text':df.T.index})
df_new['text'] = df_new['text'].str.strip("'")
#create a new column for group
df_new['group']=1
#cumsum the column names 
df_new['name'] = df_new.groupby('group')['text'].apply(lambda x: (x + ' ').cumsum().str.strip() + ",")
del df_new['group']
```